Carpet pages from Leningrad Codex
The editions of Lenigrad Codex have the following picture on its cover:

The photograph was taken by Bruce and Kenneth Zuckerman, West Semitic Research, in collaboration with the Ancient Biblical Manuscripts Center. Courtesy Russian National Library (Saltykov-Schedrin).
There is small handwritten text which creates lines and words in the picture. Does anyone know what it says? Although it looks like a picture from the back of Leningrad Codex, is it possible to find out from which manuscript was it taken?
The wikipedia page for Leningrad Codex does not have the above cover page. Instead it gives the following cover:

It also has a very intricate design. I am also curious about the contents of this cover as well.
Where can one get information about both covers? Do we know the artisan?

These sorts of decorations are common for the era. Usually it'll be either be a extended masoretic note or a bunch of "good luck" verses.

Interesting question. As it turns out, a PhD dissertation was written on these pages and the other illustrated pages of the Leningrad Codex, and is open-access on ProQuest: S. L. Schmidt, 'The Carpet Illuminations of Codex Leningrad National Library of Russia Ms. Evr. I B 19a', University of the Holy Land 2019.
It seems that none of these pages are cover pages per se, but are found at the end of the manuscript. These sorts of pages are defined as "carpet pages" because they resemble elaborate carpets (think especially oriental-type carpets).
The first one you ask about is folio 478r (r = recto, the front or right side of a page; v = verso, the back or left side of a page), discussed on pp. 267-278, with a table of the verses on this page appearing in pp. 270-277. Schmidt also included an artistic discussion of the page, suggesting that the page represents

"a visual construct of the idea of God occupying the heavens above. Israel occupies the earthly realm in the lower half of the folium and the arcade of the Temple, with the messianic hope for the believer who obeys and goes up for pilgrimage on the Feasts."

The second page you ask about, folio 474r, is discussed on pp. 159-173. This page features a dedicatory colophon in the center, including the name of the scribe - who is also the artist, Shmuel ben Yaakov - and masoretic notes and verses around, listed in pp. 161-173.
It should be noted that both pages, as well as other pages, are discussed in other chapters of the dissertation, besides the above-referenced pages, which are part of a section of the work that discusses each page by itself. So it would likely be worthwhile for you to read or at least skim the entire work, to gain a better understanding of these pages.

Thank you. I saw modern examples when they would inscribe a entire sefer tehilim into an art work. These are wonderful ancient examples.

The selection of verses is worthy of a mussar sefer!
